# SQL populating custom table with composite primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql, join

I am running into a problem where I am trying populate a table that consists of users and tasks.  The table currently has some users who have completed tasks and there is a constraint where a user cannot complete the same task twice.  Here is an example:

```
*UsersTable*                *TasksTable*
**Users**                   **Users**       **TaskCompleted**
User1                       User1           Task1
User1                       User1           Task2
User3                       User3           Task1
User4                       User4           Task3
User5
User6
```

My goal is to check if all Users have completed Task1 and if they haven’t then insert into the “TasksTable” to show that they have completed Task1.  Then I would like to do the same thing for Task2.  There should be no changes to Task3.

All of my attempts have failed so I am back to square one with no real working code.  However, my idea is to compare a list of all users to a list of users who have the Task in question already completed and to then diff the two lists to get a list of users who have not completed the task.  I am not sure how I can write this out though. Any suggestions or examples would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the structure of the tables you are using? What query have you tried so far?

Comment: The structure of the tables I am using is shown above.  I have a Users table and Tasks Table.  I updated the question with an explanation of the query I am trying to create.  I will try to write out the query I am attempting to create again and will update the question with that code as well.  Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being one of those questions where you start figuring out the answer after you type it out step by step and post it.

As I had stated in my question... I need to compare a list of all users to a list of users who have the Task in question already completed and to then diff the two lists to get a list of users who have not completed the task.

This is how I solved it:

```
INSERT INTO TasksTable
SELECT Users, 1
FROM
(
SELECT Users
FROM UsersTable

EXCEPT

SELECT Users
FROM TasksTable
WHERE TaskCompleted = Task1
) as UsersWithoutCompletedTask
```

And then I did the same thing for Task2.

Answer (score 0):

So you can utilise an anti-join to reveal all the users who have not completed tasks 1 and 2. Then you can use this list to insert into the tasks table.

See:

```
INSERT INTO tasks
SELECT 
user 
completed_task_1 AS completed_tasks
FROM 
(
SELECT 
user_1 
, completed_tasks_1
(
SELECT 
user AS user_1
, "Task 1" AS completed_tasks_1
FROM 
users
) t1
LEFT JOIN 
tasks b
ON user_1 = b.user AND completed_tasks_1 = b.completed_tasks
) anti_join 
WHERE user IS NULL
```

Then repeat this but change "Task 1" to "Task 2"